# How can send link group without show info ? Bot Telegram

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I send link public group to user.
When receive to user.show info the group.

How can send link group without show info ?

[image: streenshut send link to user]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are human, just wait preview before sending that, and click `X` to disable.

For bots, add `disable_web_page_preview=true` in parameter, you can find usage in [API Doc](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage).